# Interface inheritance - changing method parameters

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I have difficulties understanding the java way of interpreting interface inheritance, example:

```
public interface Model {
    Model getModel();
    void setModel(Model model);
}

public class BaseModel implements Model {
    @Override
    public BaseModel getModel() { return  null; } // works

    @Override
    public void setModel(BaseModel model) {} // compilation error, it wants Model instead of BaseModel
}
```

Could anyone explain why the first method works, and the second doesn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to understand this, you should ask yourself "can I substitude `BaseModel` for any usage of the `Model` interface"?

When you specialize the return value, this works fine. Even if `getModel()` returns a `BaseModel`, it can always be assigned to a `Model` variable.

```
Model model = myModel.getModel();
```

The other way round is not true, however:

```
SomeOtherModel other = ...;
myModel.setModel(other); // no problem
myBaseModel.setModel(other); // other is not a BaseModel!
```

if `setModel` were to accept a `BaseModel` parameter you'd break its ability to be set with other implementations of `Model`. Hence, this is not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

Your first method's return type is [covariant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) and is allowed and return type is not a part of method signature hence its allowed

While parameter to a method is a part of signature and has to strictly follow the interface signature and hence it fails in your case.

Now since you annotated your method with `@Override`, you are trying to override the method hence compiler complains about the same. If you just remove that and implement method as per interface in addition to existing implementation then you will overload the method.

Answer (score 3):

It's how function overriding works.

1. The function parameters have to be exactly identical.
2. The return types *can* be different but *must* be related.

So in your case, `getModel` is fine since the return type (`BaseModel`) is related to `Model`, but `setModel` is not valid since the parameter types are dissimilar.

Answer (score 2):

Method name and parameter types makes a method signature in Java and not the return type. When you override a method the signature of the method should be the same
If you change the signature it ll be overloading and not overriding - to see it if you remove the @Override annotation it ll work.